# PostgreSQL.How to output filter rows and analytic result for it in one function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Currently,I create A function which returns setof books(a table).
And then,I create B function which returns a table.The table is a analytics result for A.
Finally,the page both need A's result for detail and need B's result for analytics result.
You can see,almost the same compute twice.
How to combine to one function?

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution for problems like this is [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS).

For example, to get a list of books as well as the average number of copies on store, you can write a query like:

```
SELECT title, author,
       avg(copies) OVER () AS copies_average
FROM books;

┌─────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│              title              │     author      │   copies_average    │
├─────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ The Art of Computer Programming │ Donald E. Knuth │ 72.0000000000000000 │
│ The Tao of Programming          │ Geoffrey Hames  │ 72.0000000000000000 │
└─────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
(2 rows)
```

The last column is the same for all rows and is the average applied to the complete result set (because we used an empty window definition).

The table is scanned only once.

You could use a query like this in your function `A` and not have a function `B` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I konw window functions.But for my problem it is not a solution.
I create a table for A.and then calculate it for B.